# Multiple States in Angular Animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have the following animation:

```
export function ExpandAnimation(): AnimationTriggerMetadata {
  return trigger('ExpandAnimation', [
    state('false', style({height: '0px'})),
    transition('false => true', [animate('0.6s ease-in-out', style({height: '*'}))]),
    transition('false => true', [animate('0.6s ease-in-out', style({height: '*'}))])
  ]);
}
```

Is it possible for me to add another state to it so that when going from `true => false`, I can have the body "compress" instead of expand? Or would I have to write another animation function, `CompressAnimation()` for example.

I was thinking of something like:

```
export function CompressExpandAnimation(): AnimationTriggerMetadata {
  return trigger('CompressExpandAnimation', [
    state('false', style({height: '0px'})),
    transition('false => true', [animate('0.6s ease-in-out', style({height: '*'}))]),
    transition('false => true', [animate('0.6s ease-in-out', style({height: '*'}))])

    state('true', style({height: '*'})),
    transition('true => false', [animate('0.6s ease-in-out', style({height: '0px'}))]),
    transition('true=> false', [animate('0.6s ease-in-out', style({height: '0px'}))])
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your transitions are duplicated but yes you only have to add a state to expand or reduce the height of the div.

Here is a simple animation you can use :

```
export const CompressExpandAnimation = [
  trigger('CompressExpandAnimation', [
    state('true', style({ 'height': '*' })),
    state('false', style({ 'height': '0px' })),
    transition('* => *', animate(700)),
  ]),
]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks